# Авторизация с помощью redbean не подключается к БД

Tags: mysql, redbeanphp

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'Could not
>   connect to database (reg).' in
>   D:\OpenServer\domains\www.bike-news.com\libs\rb.php:929 Stack trace:
>    #0  D:\OpenServer\domains\www.bike-news.com\libs\rb.php(699): RedBeanPHP\Driver\RPDO->connect()
>     #1 
>   D:\OpenServer\domains\www.bike-news.com\libs\rb.php(953):
>   RedBeanPHP\Driver\RPDO->runQuery('show tables', Array)
>     #2 
>   D:\OpenServer\domains\www.bike-news.com\libs\rb.php(974):
>   RedBeanPHP\Driver\RPDO->GetAll('show tables', Array)
>     #3 
>   D:\OpenServer\domains\www.bike-news.com\libs\rb.php(3675):
>   RedBeanPHP\Driver\RPDO->GetCol('show tables', Array)
>     #4 
>   D:\OpenServer\domains\www.bike-news.com\libs\rb.php(5963):
>   RedBeanPHP\Adapter\DBAdapter->getCol('show tables')
>     #5 
>   D:\OpenServer\domains\www.bike-news.com\libs\rb.php(5285):
>   RedBeanPHP\QueryWriter\MySQL->getTables()
>     #6 
>   D:\OpenServer\domains\www.bike-news.com\libs\rb.php(7764):
>   RedBeanPHP\QueryWriter\AQueryWriter->tableExists('users')
>     #7 
>   D:\OpenServer\domains\www.bike-news.com\libs\rb.php(7862):
>   RedBeanPHP\Repository->tab in
>   D:\OpenServer\domains\www.bike-news.com\libs\rb.php on line 929

Файл db.php

```
<?php
  require  "libs/rb.php";
  R::setup( 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=reg','root', ' ' );
?>
```

Comment: А зачем у вас в пароле пробел стоит?

Comment: Я и порты проверял, и в  db.php порты вводил, не помогло, а на пробел даже не обратил внимания.Спасибо всё работает